# RoR pattern for a registration page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a action/view named: join

And I post the the 'create' action.

What should my create action look like, I want to pre-populate some fields if the creation process had an error in it (like say the email address).

So far I have:

```
def create

      @user = User.new(params[:user])   

      if @user.save

      end

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a new action for registration, do this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to success_page
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

+1 for @PeterWong but if possible why not use authentication, authorization plugin. There are many for rails, most famous ones would be

1 - Authlogic - http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic

2 - Devise - http://github.com/plataformatec/devise

3 - REstful Authentication - http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication

cheers

sameera